# How to solve internal error from server (test)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

guys. I'm testing method and in test it's name is **testGetAuthorizedUserPublicInfo**. This method have to return an User object. (So i created **getUser** method which return our new user).
Then after calling some methods on mockMvc objects try to perform get method (url is the same like in Controller class).

But i getting 500 response (instead of 200).

Can anyone say where is my mistake?? it would be really great )

`

```
package com.softserve.academy.spaced.repetition.controller;


import com.softserve.academy.spaced.repetition.controller.handler.ExceptionHandlerController;
import com.softserve.academy.spaced.repetition.domain.Account;
import com.softserve.academy.spaced.repetition.domain.Person;
import com.softserve.academy.spaced.repetition.domain.User;
import com.softserve.academy.spaced.repetition.domain.enums.AccountStatus;
import com.softserve.academy.spaced.repetition.domain.enums.AuthenticationType;
import com.softserve.academy.spaced.repetition.domain.enums.ImageType;
import com.softserve.academy.spaced.repetition.domain.enums.LearningRegime;
import com.softserve.academy.spaced.repetition.service.UserService;
import org.hamcrest.Matchers;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UserControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    private static final long USER_ID = 1L;

    @InjectMocks
    UserController userController;

    @Mock
    UserService userService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(userController)
                .setControllerAdvice(new ExceptionHandlerController())
                .build();
    }


    @Test
    public void testGetAuthorizedUserPublicInfo() throws Exception {
        when(userService.getAuthorizedUser()).thenReturn(getUser());
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/user/details")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", Matchers.is(1)));


    }

    private User getUser() {
        Account account;
        Person person;
        User user;

        account = new Account();
        account.setId(USER_ID);
        account.setPassword("12345678");
        account.setEmail("a@a.a");
        account.setAuthenticationType(AuthenticationType.LOCAL);
        account.setStatus(AccountStatus.ACTIVE);
        account.setDeactivated(false);
        account.setLastPasswordResetDate(new Date());
        account.setLearningRegime(LearningRegime.BAD_NORMAL_GOOD_STATUS_DEPENDING);
        account.setCardsNumber(1);

        person = new Person();
        person.setId(USER_ID);
        person.setFirstName("firstname");
        person.setLastName("lastname");
        person.setImageType(ImageType.NONE);

        user = new User();
        user.setId(USER_ID);
        user.setAccount(account);
        user.setPerson(person);

        return user;
    }
}
```

`

here is what i've got after executing this test method

`

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :500
 <Click to see difference>


    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:54)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:81)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$10.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:664)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:171)
    at com.softserve.academy.spaced.repetition.controller.UserControllerTest.testGetAuthorizedUserPublicInfo(UserControllerTest.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)


Process finished with exit code 255
```

`

Comment: Check server logs

Comment: You need to check the logs to find the exact name of the exception thrown or what is being passed to that Assertion.